# How to get BSOD Error info, as the PC restarts and I could not take the screenshot

Tags: windows-11, bsod

My laptop is restarting from time to time after BSOD, it shows some error but it quickly restarts before I can ready some information. Is there any place in windows logs/events from where I can get the exact error I got?

The misc. errors I got in last weeks are:

```
IRQL ...
Registery_Filter_...
Thread_Exception_Not...
```

Here is the most recent minidumps
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lF2DMjYsIJXDp-M1sKWh67V-AR12RY4Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps update all drivers. Best to use the computer manufacturer’s Driver Update App.  Common fix for IRQ less or equal errors.  Look in the Windows mini dump folder for dmp files

Comment: If you see `.dmp` files in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`, zip up a few of the most recent ones and post online for us to analyze (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: @harrymc dump links are added to question

Comment: I would open a DMP file with Nirsoft Blue Screen View. Try posting the file in your question. Google is not smart enough to use the correct App unfortunately.

Comment: Run WinDBG against the file that was create and provide the relevant information from the analysis output and edit your question. This is most certainly something you can provide for us.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of the `.dmp` crash dumps using
[BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) :

- All the crashes happen inside the kernel
- In 4 out of the 5 dumps the driver call stack is unavailable and the
  error is STOP 0x0000000a, which usually means that a driver or
  Windows Kernel Mode used an incorrect memory address, and
  memory corruption could indeed explain why the call stack is
  unavailable
- In one crash the error was STOP 0x00000135 inside the driver
  `WdFilter.sys`, which seems to be the
  Microsoft antimalware file system filter driver.

I would suggest to try and find more information in the Event Viewer.

For the possibility that you have a bad memory RAM, I would
suggest to download and run
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
for many hours and even overnight. This would test not only the RAM
but also the general functioning of the computer.

Comment: I have 2 modules each of 16GB, let me try them one by one. Maybe I m getting this bcoz of issue of one bad module.